# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called. Running in IDE but not in as a batch file

Tags: python

I have the following script where this is the first part. I works fine in PyCharm but because it is build as a scraper to run in "Windows Task Scheduler" I have converted it to a batch file. Here it spits out: ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! 
The value "actual" is a "tuple" containing a string and a float before I try to convert it to a dataframe.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Import from ---
Response = requests.get('https://---.com/latest', auth=('---', '---'))
Data = Response.json()

Actual='ac_power:', Data['United Kingdom']['ac_power']
Actual=pd.DataFrame(Actual)
Actual=Actual.drop([0])
```

Does anybody have an idea of why it will run in PyCharm but not through the batch file?

Comment: The better way to instantiate a dataframe would be with a dict, instead of a tuple. And then the second element should be a list or a (NumPy) array, not a single float.

Comment: What do you mean by "batch file"? Do you mean a Python script? A batch file will not work with Python code.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you trying to call the python script from the windows scheduler. Could you please share the bat file that you are calling from the task scheduler, could you please paste the exact error you get.